# f 77 compiler not found while installing R in Redhat 5

Tags: r, redhat

While installing R i am getting the following error...

```
[root@bivm R-2.15.2]# ./configure 
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking for working aclocal... missing
checking for working autoconf... missing
checking for working automake... missing
checking for working autoheader... missing
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... /bin/gtar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for makeinfo... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /usr/bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... /usr/bin/firefox
using default browser ... /usr/bin/firefox
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... no
checking for evince... /usr/bin/evince
checking for notangle... false
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gfortran... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for ftn... no
checking for g95... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for fc... no
configure: error: No F77 compiler found
```

I installed gcc compiler.But still showing the same.

```
[root@bivm R-2.15.2]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `gfortran`, which is probably by default not part of the gcc package. You can have a look at what packages are fortran related:

```
yum search "*fortran*"
```

And find the package that contains `gfortran`, something like `gcc4-gfortran`, and install it.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing `gfortran` in my Ubuntu 14.04, but now another error is arrived `configure: error: --with-x=yes (default) and X11 headers/libs are not available`